# Org-mode \ang from siunitx is overruled by the \angle symbol on pdf export

Tags: org-export, latex, org-mode

I'm trying to use the package siunitx to format my scientific notations/values more nicely, but I can't get one thing to work, possibly due to my pdf-process.

I type in my orgfile something like this: `\ang{95;13;14}N`.

Expecting it to output: `95°13'14"`. In stead it outputs 
`∠{95;13;14}N.`

I `#+INCLUDE:` this file with my LaTeX settings:

```
# page setup
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper] 
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt] 
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [twoside] 

# placement of TOC anywhere
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{titletoc}

# mathtools
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{mathtools}

# fix margin
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[innermargin=1.5in,outermargin=1.25in,vmargin=1.25in]{geometry}

# citation style
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[authordate,bibencoding=utf8,strict,backend=biber,url=false,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
# (internal) links
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citebordercolor={0 1 0},linktocpage,pdfstartview=FitH,anchorcolor=blue,filecolor=blue,menucolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
# don't forget to #+LATEX_HEADER: \addbibresource

# chemical formulae
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

# SI units simplified
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
```

And I use this line for my latex-pdf process in [my init file](https://github.com/japhir/ArchConfigs/blob/master/Laptop/myinit.org):

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
     '("latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f"))
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

I've opened up the exported .tex file and there I can see the problem:
org mode has exported `\(\angle\)\{65;;\}N`, so it seems like emacs is extending `\ang` into `\angle`. If I manually edit the tex file and export it works correctly. 
Any idea how to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable entities.
Or if you want to keep using entities remove the "ang" entry.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org-entities
  (setq org-entities
        (cl-remove-if (lambda (x) (and (listp x) (equal (car x) "ang"))) org-entities)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to make sure to add math delimiters as described in [@LaTeX{} fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html#LaTeX-fragments).

`\(\ang{45;23;23}\)N`

Comment: This still doesn't solve everything for me though.

If I want to add chemical equations with isotopes in text-mode with `\ce{^{13}C}` for example, it returns `{¹³C}`. Forcing it to math-mode works but will result in different outlining right?

Comment: [here](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Chemistry_notation_using_mhchem#Basics) they say that `\ce{}` always needs math delimiters, so I guess it's no problem :).